# SQS : ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage metrics - 5 times than expected

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs

I have a metrics and alarm set on our DLQ's metrics - ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage. Threshold : ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage >= 345600 for 1 datapoints within 5 minutes

345600 ~= 4 days.

Sharing a specific instance to give better understanding of the issue : Recently we observed that 7 days before metrics for ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage was at 0 and in 7 days metrics spiked to 3M seconds i.e. ~35 days, but ideally it should have been only 7 days. So, it is 5 times the expected metrics.

One possibility is that ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage metrics gets emit at period of every 1 minute and we have metrics at sum of 5 minutes, which may be the reason leading it to 5 times the expected metrics. If that is the case then should we update our alarms to 1min i.e. to - >= 345600 for 1 datapoints within 1 minute ?

Please guide me as this is leading to false positive alarms as we are getting alarm raised on ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage as metrics is 5 times than expected.

Comment: You should consider taking average of 5 minutes instead of sum or maximum or minimum.